# ¿Es correcto usar el mismo id y name en los input de un formulario html?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Quisiera saber si es una buena practica colocar lo mismo en id y en name cuando voy a programar, por ejemplo, en HTML y PHP. ¿Podría afectar el código cuando ya este avanzado? ¿Que consecuencias podría tener hacerlo?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existe una dificultad cuando se asigna el mismo nombre y id a un elemento. Los navegadores Internet Explorer inferiores a la versión 10 no saben distinguir entre `name` y `id` cuando se usa el método `getElementsByName()`.

Lo dice Mozilla en su [documentación oficial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByName):

> The `getElementsByName` method works differently in different
>   browsers. In IE < 10, `getElementsByName()` method will also return
>   elements that have an id attribute with the specified value. **So you
>   should be careful not to use the same string as both a name and an
>   ID**.
>
> ---
>
> El método `getElementsByName` funciona de forma diferente
>   en diferentes navegadores. En IE <10, el método `getElementsByName()`
>   también devolverá elementos que tienen un atributo id con el valor
>   especificado. **Por lo que debe tener cuidado de no utilizar la misma
>   cadena como un nombre y un ID.**

Hay que decir también que en la [especificación de HTML 5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) **el atributo `name` queda obsoleto en los elementos siguientes**:

- `a` (excepto en lo indicado en la [sección 11.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/obsolete.html#obsolete-but-conforming-features) de la especificación)
- `embed`
- `img`
- `option`

En todos ellos **se recomienda usar el atributo `id` solamente**.

Comment: Es interesante, porque lamentablemente, algunos desarrollos necesitan tener en cuenta estos navegadores.

Comment: @A.Cedano Yo creo que un software deber ser utilizable en el mayor rango posible de navegadores y plataformas, y si usar lo mismo en ID y en name significa que mi software esta restringido en algunos navegadores, concluyo que no es una buena practica.

Comment: @YomismoDJ Es correcto. Y mucho más sabiendo que la versión del navegador depende de cada cliente. Y además no existe ningún motivo por el cual haya que dar el mismo valor al name y al id de un elemento. Como decía en otro comentario a mi me gusta diferenciarlos porque **cada cosa es cada cosa** aunque se parezcan, así que les asigno casi el mismo valor, agregando una _n al final cuando se trata del nombre. Y... visto que name empieza a ser obsoleto en algunos elementos de HTML5, lo usaré solamente cuando sea estrictamente necesario.

Comment: No es para discutir, pero hacer una pagina que funcione *bien* en todos los navegadores es una utopia o es algo para grandes teams con tiempo y presupuesto. Ojo x que este es solo uno de los problemas a los cuales te enfrentas para soportar IE. El 4% del mercado tiene IE8, el cual es aun mas dificil de soportar por sus muchas otras cosas que no funcionan bien). Hay que manejar un equilibrio entre el costo y el beneficio ;)

Comment: Si les interesa [aqui](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2017/04/19/modernizing-dom-tree-microsoft-edge/#URsqSF3UffeQAA2Q.97) hay un articulo que salio hoy sobre los cambios que estan realizando del core de IE a Edge, interesante y da algo de miedo leer como estaba hecho.

Answer (score 10):

`id` y `name` son cosas diferentes pero no hay problema que tengan el mismo valor.

`id` es para identificar univocamente un elemento dentro del documento. Los ids no deberian repetirse y en caso de repeticion, la función `getElementById` retorna el primero de los elementos. Se usa principalmente del lado del cliente para localizar y modificar algún elemento particular.

`name` en cambio, se lo utiliza habitualmente para identificar los elementos de un formulario: `<input>`, `<textarea>` y los `<select>` cuando se envía un formulario al servidor. Especifica la clave de la pareja `clave/valor` que se recibe en el servidor. Osea que ya en el servidor los datos están asociados al `name` del elemento y no a su `id` (el cual se desconoce del lado del servidor).

Basicmante `<input name="nombre">` llega al servidor en la forma de... `$POST["nombre"]` (si se usa POST).

Hay que notar que `getElementsByName` retorna siempre un arreglo aunque encuentre un solo elemento.

Otra cosa importante de `name` es que si varios elementos tienen el mismo `name`, dependiendo del elemento se comporta diferente:

Si tienes varios `<input type="submit">` con el mismo nombre, al servidor llega el `value` del botón presionado y no los demás, de forma que se puede identificar fácilmente un botón. Algo similar sucede con los `radio`.

En conjunto con `php`, si se usa un `name` como este: `name="nombre[]"` puede leerse directamente como un array en server side así: `$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];` (por ejemplo en un conjunto de `checkbox` o de `text`).