# Envio de datos de formulario html

Tags: php, html

Buenos dias. Tengo un formulario que recoge los datos que se insertan y se envian a una pagina en php encargada de hacer el envio. Todo el proceso se realiza bien, salvo el campo referente a un select, cuyo campo no se envia, ni siquiera en blanco. Adjunto el fragmento de codigo:

```
 <form id="Formulario" name="formucontacto" action="envio.php">

                <fieldset>
                    <input type="text" id='nombre' name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre..." required>
                    <input id='mail' name="mail" type = 'email' placeholder="Introduce tu correo electrónico" required>
                    <input id='Telefono' name="telefono" type = 'text' placeholder="Introduce tu telefono" required>
                    <select id="producto" name='producto' required>
                        <option value="" default>-- Selecciona tu producto --</option>
                        <option value="1">Producto1</option>
                        <option value="2">Producto2</option>
                        <option value="3">Producto3</option>
                        <option value="4">Producto4</option>
                        <option value="5">Producto5</option>
                        <option value="6">Otro...</option>
                    </select>

                   <input type="submit" onclick="if (validarcontacto()) this.form.submit()" id="solicitar" value="SOLICITAR"/>                    
                </form>
          </fieldset>
```

Al pulsar en el boton SOLICITAR se llama a una funcion donde se verifica si los campos estan vacios o no, y si todo es correcto, el formulario se manda a una pagina php con la siguiente funcion al inicio de ella:

```
    <?php
foreach($_REQUEST as $campo=>$valor){
  .$texto .= $campo.": ".$valor."\n\n"; 
}
$cabeceras = 'From: $config_email'."\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8'."\r\n";
$cabeceras .= 'Bcc: correo@correo.com' . "\r\n";

//Envio de mail
mail("correo@correo.com", "Mensaje desde la Web", nl2br($texto), $cabeceras);  
?>
```

Como he dicho antes, funciona correctamente, pero el campo select no me lo manda, he probado poniendole un atributo name como al resto, pero todo igual.
Agradezco toda ayuda, muchas gracias.

Comment: Para que un campo se envíe debe tener un atributo `name`.

Comment: Lo se, se lo puse pero el resultado fue el mismo.

Comment: Actualiza entonces el contenido de tu pregunta, porque todo el que lo vea así te va a decir lo mismo. ¿Puedes hacer un print_r($_POST) y decirnos qué te muestra?

Comment: @Muriano cuando hago un print_r de $_POST, al igual que  de $_REQUEST me aparece Array(nombre => valor, mail => valor, telefono => valor). Me recoje correctamente los campos salvo el proveniente del select.

Comment: @AntonioMP87 puedes mostrar tu codigo validarcontacto()?

Comment: Te falta el method POST en el formullario :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He probado el formulario tal y como lo tienes en tu pregunta, y no hay ningún problema, al hacer post se envía esto:

```
envio.php?nombre=NPrueba&mail=prueba%40example.com&telefono=5559990&producto=3
```

como puedes apreciar al final, el producto se postea bien.

**¿Cuál podría ser el problema?**

Hace poco respondí a la pregunta siguiente: [¿Es correcto usar el mismo id y name en los input de un formulario html?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63793/29967)

Si estás usando tu formulario en una versión de Internet Explorer inferior a la v. 10, o por otro motivo cualquiera... Javascript no sabe distinguir entre `id` y `name` si dichos atributos tienen el mismo valor, precisamente lo que ocurre en tu caso.

Esa puede ser una posible causa de por qué `producto` no se está posteando, en tu caso.

Puedes probar **poniendo un `id` distinto a la etiqueta**, para depurar esa posibilidad, o sea:

```
 <select id="producto_id" name="producto" required>
```

Sería interesante que pruebes y que comentes el tipo de navegador que tienes, pues es el único motivo por el que veo te podría estar fallando.

---

**Nota:**
Al leer esto en tu pregunta:

> *he probado poniendole un atributo name como al resto, pero todo igual.*

quiero simplemente señalar que los datos enviados por `_$POST` son recuperados por el atributo `name`, **no por el atributo `id`**, de forma que un elemento que no tenga indicado el atributo `name` no puede ser recuperado en el `_$POST`.

**P.D.** Por otra parte, es buena la uniformidad cuando escribes los atributos de tus etiquetas. Lo digo porque a veces usas `'...'` y otras veces usas `"..."`,

por ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" id='nombre' name="nombre" placeholder="Introduce tu nombre..." required>
                      ^      ^ 
                     ¿por qué no usas " " también ahí?
```

conviene que te decidas por uno de los dos y que escribas todo uniformemente.

Answer (score 1):

Prueba a cambiar:

```
<option value="" default>-- Selecciona tu producto --</option>
```

Por:

```php
<option value="" selected>-- Selecciona tu producto --</option>
//               ^^^^^^^^
```

Según la documentación de w3schools el atributo `default` no existe en ese contexto: [Enlace](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp)

También he visto que te falta el atributo `method` en la etiqueta del formulario, sin este atributo el formulario no enviará nada por `POST`, añade a tu etiqueta form el atributo `method="POST"`

Quedaría tal que así:

```
<form id="Formulario" name="formucontacto" method="POST" action="envio.php">
```

Comment: @Heichi He hecho el cambio que me sugieres y no hay cambio alguno.

Comment: @AntonioMP87 He actualizado la respuesta con la posible solución.