# Inserción de datos mysqli php. ¿qué estoy haciendo mal?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Resulta que estoy haciendo un crud con mysqli php html y bootstrap y a la hora de insertar los datos a la bd por medio de php me dice lo siguiente:Notice: Undefined index: id_user in C:\wamp64\www\legales\register.php on line 5. Esto me lo repite con cada uno de los $_POST

el codigo php sera el siguiente:

```
<?php

include "connection.php";

 $id_user = $_POST['id_user'];
$name_user = $_POST['name_user'];
$apPaternouser = $_POST['apPaternouser'];
$apMaternouser = $_POST['apMaternouser'];
$nacionalidad_usr =$_POST['nacionalidad_usr'];
$turuser = $_POST['turuser'];
$dv = $_POST['dv'];
$fechanac = $_POST['fechanac'];
$regiones = $_POST['regiones'];
$comunas = $_POST['comunas'];
$direccion_usr = $_POST['direccion_usr'];
$email_usr = $_POST['email_usr'];
$areanumber_usr = $_POST['areanumber_usr'];
$number_usr = $_POST['number_usr'];
$mobil_usr = $_POST['mobil_usr'];

$insertar = "insert into users (id_user, name_user, apPaternouser, apMaternouser, nacionalidad_usr, turuser, dv, fechanac, regiones , comunas, direccion_usr, email_usr, areanumber_usr, number_usr, mobil_usr) values
  ('$id_user', '$name_user', '$apPaternouser', '$apMaternouser', 
'$nacionalidad_usr', '$turuser', '$dv', '$fechanac', '$region_usr', '$region_usr', '$direccion_usr', '$direccion_usr', '$email_usr', '$areanumber_usr, '$number_usr', '$mobil_usr')";

$resultado =mysqli_query($con, $insertar)
or die("error al insertar datos");
echo "datos ingresados";

?>
```

una vez funcionando como podria hacer que quedara el codigo mas seguro sin necesidad de usar pdo?

edit:no veo error en los id ni for. codigo HTML, :

```
<div class="card card-register mx-auto mt-5">
      <div class="card- header">Registrar una Cuenta</div>
      <div class="card-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="form-row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="id_user">ID Usuario</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="id_user" type="text" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Ingrese id">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="name_user">Nombre</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="name_user" type="text" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

Dado ha que aún no puedo solucionar mi problema me veo a seguir en el post, probe cambiar el id por un nombre distinto al de name como me mencionaron, y tampoco se soluciona el error, ya no me dice undefined index, pero me da error al insertar datos

Comment: La respuesta es sencilla porque te lo está diciendo el error, no existe el indice 'id_user' es decir el arreglo $_POST no tiene un elemento con key id_user, pon el código de como mandas el post porque ahí debe estar el problema no lo debes estar enviando bien

Comment: Verifica que este correctamente escrito la propiedad name del input en tu formulario.

Comment: Tu input con id `id_user` le falta el atributo `name='id_user'` y por ende también al input con id `name_user` y cualquier otro input donde no hayas definido su atributo `name`

Comment: Tu CRUD es muy peligroso. Espero que un hacker no se encuentre con tu formulario en línea, porque casi seguro lo vas a lamentar. Cuando resuelvas lo del atributo `name`  que te han dicho,   considera proteger tus consultas de la Inyección SQL.

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Envio de datos de formulario html](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68509/envio-de-datos-de-formulario-html)

Answer (score 2):

Para enviar formularios por POST el estándar es agregar el atributo name en los inputs que contendrán la información, el error `Undefined index: id_user in C:\wamp64\www\legales\register.php on line 5` es normal ya que al no especificar el name efectivamente el campo `$_POST['id_user'];` no existe por lo que aparte del id debes colocar el atributo en los inputs correspondientes:

```
 <input class="form-control" id="id_user" name="id_user" type="text" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Ingrese id">.
```

un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="id_user">ID Usuario</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="id_user" name="id_user" type="text" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Ingrese id">
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label for="name_user">Nombre</label>
                <input class="form-control" id="name_user" name="name_user" type="text" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre">
              </div>
```

Usa el atributo `name` en los inputs ejempleo :name="name_user"

```html
$insertar = "insert into users (id_user, name_user, apPaternouser, apMaternouser, nacionalidad_usr, turuser, dv, fechanac, regiones , comunas, direccion_usr, email_usr, areanumber_usr, number_usr, mobil_usr) values
  ('$id_user', '$name_user', '$apPaternouser', '$apMaternouser', 
'$nacionalidad_usr', '$turuser', '$dv', '$fechanac', '$region_usr', '$region_usr', '$direccion_usr', '$direccion_usr', '$email_usr', '$areanumber_usr', '$number_usr', '$mobil_usr')";
```

Copia esa query al parecer fue un ''.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Prueba de esta forma para todas la variables, ademas te falta el atributo `name` a los inputs:

```
$id_user = isset($_POST['id_user']) ? $_POST['id_user'] : '';
```

2.- Revisa tu query en la variable `$areanumber_usr` te falta cerrar la comilla simple.
3.- Para hacer mas segura la query puedes usar `mysqli_prepare` mas informacion [aqui](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli.prepare.php) o [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/c%C3%B3mo-evitar-la-inyecci%C3%B3n-sql-en-php)

ejemplo de como seria:

```
$insertar = "insert into users (id_user, name_user,..., mobil_usr) values
  (?, ?,..., ?)";
$prepara=mysqli_prepare($coneccion,$insertar);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($prepara, "ss...s", $id_user, $name_user,...,$mobil_usr);// (s) quiere decir cadena de texto e (i) es para los enteros
if(mysqli_stmt_execute($prepara)){
echo "Correcto";
}else{
echo "Fallo";
}
```