# input type=submit no funciona en internet explorer

Tags: html5, formularios, internet-explorer

Hola,

Tengo un formulario que hace una llamada POST con un `<input type="submit">` para que se realice la llamada al servidor. El caso es que me funciona correctamente en Firefox y en Chrome, pero no en IE.

He estado observando en varios hilos que para que funcione hay que añadirle un *name*, pero ni así consigo que se efectue la llamada.

¿Le ha sucedido esto a alguien? Dejo el código:

```
<form action="{{url('simulador/result')}}" method="POST">

        <div class="col-md-12 setup-content text-center cajas-inicio" id="step-1">
            <button id="activate-step-2" class="action-button shadow animate blue">Siguiente</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="col-md-12 setup-content text-center cajas-inicio" id="step-2">
            <h1 class="text-center"> Fecha de nacimiento del conyuge</h1></br>
            <h2>&larr; Seleccione una de las dos opciones &rarr;</h2>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="/img/icons/holding-hands.png" alt="">
                        <input type="radio" name="calculo" value="si" id="radio1" class="radio">
                        <label for="radio1" style="background-color: gainsboro">Calculo con conyuge</label> 
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <img src="/img/icons/school-teacher.png" alt="">
                        <input type="radio" name="calculo" value="no" id="radio2" class="radio">
                        <label for="radio2" style="background-color: gainsboro">Calculo sin conyuge</label>

                    </div>
                </div>

            <div id="calendar">
                <p>Introduzca la fecha de nacimiento del conyuge</p><br>
                <input type="text" name="fechaConyuge" id="datepicker"></br>
            </div>
            <input type="submit" class="action-button shadow animate blue" name="validar">
            </div>
        </div>

</form>
```

Comment: Hola Rafael. El problema no está en el HTML. Revisa el resto de tu código. Si copias el HTML que has puesto en un fichero y lo abres con IE te hace el submit del formulario. Algo más tienes que tener en tu código para que no funcione.

Comment: Si tienes comprobado y confirmado que el  action="{{url('simulador/result')}}"  enlaza bien con el archivo al que le vas a enviar los datos... opino igual que @AsierVillanueva

Comment: Si si, ya os digo que en Chrome y Firefox funciona correctamente. Tengo jQuery trabajando el DOM, pero no afecta directamente a ningún campo del formulario ni a este.

Comment: El código HTML que has puesto también funciona sin problemas en Internet Explorer. Prueba a crear un archivo HTML exclusivamente con ese código y podrás comprobarlo.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de internet explorer te está fallando?

Comment: ¿Nos pones el codigo ya rendereado? ¿Qué versión de internet explorer estás utilizando?

Comment: Al submit lo estás atrapando en algún javascript antes de que se haga el submit del form?

Comment: Sería interesante que comentes la versión de IE que estás usando y que, para depurar, **des un nombre único al `input` problemático** que no se repita en ningún otro `name` ni `id` de ningún otro elemento del HTML, ya que según la versión de IE, tener nombres (y ids) iguales en los elementos puede dar problemas en versiones de IE inferiores a la v. 10. Ver: [¿Es correcto usar el mismo id y name en los input de un formulario html?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/63793/29967)

Comment: Utilizo la versión 11 de IE. El _name_ es único. El submit no pasa por ninguna acción de javascript. El caso es que si es verdad que copiando el código efectua la llamada. Utilizo _blade_ de laravel para las vistas.

Comment: Quedo totalmente confuso con la última parte de tu comentario: _ El submit no pasa por ninguna acción de javascript. El caso es que si es verdad que copiando el código efectua la llamada. Utilizo blade de laravel para las vistas._ ¿Podrías colocar la parte Javascript también? ¿O no hay parte Javascript? _copiando el código efectúa la llamada_ ¿copiándolo dónde?

Comment: Perdón si no quedo claro, fui demasiado escueto. Lo primero decir que submit se comporta de modo natural, no valido con javascript y nada similar. En relación a la copia de código, me refiero a que es cierto que si aislo esta parte del código y la pego en IE como comentais, funciona correctamente. He resuelto la incidencia quitando parte de las acciones que ejecutaba con jQuery para ocultar cosas del DOM. Supongo que algo no se estaba llevando bien con IE.