# Se agregan campos vacios a mysql desde insert en php con ventanas modales

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql, jquery

Que tal amigos estoy luchando ocn un problema desde hace 2 dias.

Se agregan datos vacios a mi tabla pero en el insert ni siquiera llamo a ese campos es mas ni siquiera existe. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial al pie de la letra y aun asi no me deja.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=04nAeA4ZK5U&list=PLoRfWwOOv4jyR6jOLZY5biv5H0Qguq8Ea&index=7

un ejemplo de como funciona:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le damos agregar:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me sale este error:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

miren se agrega sarita (uno ya estaba) pero se agrega campo vacio en a_paterno y correo igual se agrega vacio.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Les dejo mi codigo:
**El index**

```
    <script src="librerias/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/funciones.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/alertify/alertify.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/datatable/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="librerias/datatable/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
      <div id="tabla"></div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal para registros nuevos -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="modalNuevo" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Nuevo Prospecto</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="nombre" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Correo</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="correo" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Fecha Cita</label>
            <input type="date" name="" value="" id="fechareg" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Telefono</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="telefono" class="form-control input-sm">

          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" id="guardarnuevo">Agregar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Modal para edicion de datos -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="modalEdicion" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Actualizar datos</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <input type="text" hidden="" id="idpersona" name="">
            <label>Nombre</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="nombreu" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Apellido</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="apellidou" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Fecha Cita</label>
            <input type="date" name="" value="" id="fecharegu" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Telefono</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="telefonou" class="form-control input-sm">
            <label>Correo</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="" id="correo" class="form-control input-sm">
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" id="actualizadatos" data-dismiss="modal">Actualizar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
  });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#guardarnuevo').click(function(){
      nombre = $('#nombre').val();
      fechareg = $('#fechareg').val();
      telefono =  $('#telefono').val();
      correo = $('#correo').val();
      agregardatos(nombre,correo,fechareg,telefono);
    });

    $('#actualizadatos').click(function(){
        actualizadatos();
    });
  });
</script>
```

**agregardatos**

```
<?php

  require_once "conexion.php";
  $conexion = conexion();
  $n = $_POST['nombre'];
  $c = $_POST['correo'];
  $f = $_POST['fechareg'];
  $t = $_POST['telefono'];

  $sql = "insert into llenado_formulario(nombre, correo, fechareg, celular)
                                        values('$n', '$c', '$f', '$t')";

  echo $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
?>
```

**tabla**

```
<?php
  require_once "../php/conexion.php";
  $conexion=conexion();
?>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <h2>DesarrollaT</h2>
      <table class="table table-hover table-condensed table-bordered" id="tabladinamicaload">
        <caption>
          <button class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalNuevo">
            Agregar nuevo
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
          </button>
        </caption>
          <thead>
            <tr align="center">
              <td>Imprimir</td>
              <td>Nombre</td>
              <td>Fecha Cita</td>
              <td>Teléfono</td>
              <td>Ficha Identidad</td>
              <td>Evaluacion</td>
              <td>Entrevista GDD</td>
              <td>Resultados</td>
              <td>Conexion</td>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>

          <?php
            $sql="select id, nombre, correo, fechareg, celular from llenado_formulario";
            $result=mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
            while($ver=mysqli_fetch_row($result)){

              $datos = $ver[0]."||".
                       $ver[1]."||".
                       $ver[2]."||".
                       $ver[3]."||".
                       $ver[4];
          ?>

          <tr align="center">
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
              </button>
            </td>
            <td><?php echo $ver[1] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ver[3] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $ver[4] ?></td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-print" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')"></button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
              </button>
            </td>
            <td>
              <button class="btn btn-warning glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modalEdicion" onclick="agregaform('<?php echo $datos ?>')">
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <?php
        }
          ?>
          </tbody>
      </table>
</div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tabladinamicaload').DataTable();
  });
</script>
```

**js**

```
function agregardatos(nombre, correo, fechareg, telefono) {

  cadena="nombre=" + nombre +
         "&correo=" + correo +
         "&fechareg=" + fechareg +
         "&telefono=" + telefono;

  $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"php/agregardatos.php",
    data:cadena,
    success:function(r){
      if(r==1){
        $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
        alertify.success("Agregado con Exito :)");
      }else{
        alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
      }
    }
  })
}

  function agregaform(datos){

    d = datos.split('||');

    $('#idpersona').val(d[0]);
    $('#nombreu').val(d[1]);
    $('#apellidou').val(d[2]);
    $('#fecharegu').val(d[3]);
    $('#telefonou').val(d[4]);

  }


    function actualizadatos(){

      id = $('#idpersona').val();
      nombre = $('#nombreu').val();
      apellido = $('#apellidou').val();
      fechareg = $('#fecharegu').val();
      telefono = $('#telefonou').val();

      cadena="id=" + id +
             "&nombre=" + nombre +
             "&apellido=" + apellido +
             "&fechareg=" + fechareg +
             "&telefono=" + telefono;

      $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/actualizadatos.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(r){
          if(r==1){
            $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
              alertify.success("Actualizado con Exito :)");
          }else{
              alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
            }
        }
      })
    }
```

Me van a correr si no lo hago funcionar, gracias.

Comment: la estructura de la tabla permite valores vacios?

Comment: A_paterno No y correo SI

Answer (score 0):

1. `id` es para identificar un elemento dentro del
   documento, Se usa principalmente del lado del cliente para localizar
   y modificar algún elemento particular.
2. `Name` en cambio, se lo utiliza habitualmente para identificar los
   elementos de un formulario (los cuales no estas asignando a tus
   `inputs`),  `<input name="nombre">` llega al servidor en la forma
   de... `$POST["nombre"]` (si se usa POST).

   Puedes leer este [post](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/63780/es-correcto-usar-el-mismo-id-y-name-en-los-input-de-un-formulario-html.) referente a ello
3. En la funcion `agregardatos` estas agregando a apellido en cadena

Comment: Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo en responder mi pregunta amiga, entiendo pero como explicas que los otros datos sin tener name="" o mas bien tenerlo vacio aun asi se llenan en mi base de datos. Deja les pongo el name y te aviso gracias una vez mas

Answer (score 0):

Si estas trabajando con el metodo POST en Ajax de Jquery , deberías enviar los parametros como JSON .

```
function agregardatos(nombre, correo, fechareg, telefono) {

    cadena= {
        "nombre=" : nombre ,
        "correo=" : correo ,
        "fechareg=" : fechareg ,
        "telefono=" : telefono
    }

    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"php/agregardatos.php",
        data:cadena,
        success:function(r){
            if(r==1){
                $('#tabla').load('componentes/tabla.php');
                alertify.success("Agregado con Exito :)");
            }else{
                alertify.error("Fallo el servidor :(");
            }
        }
    })
}
```

Por otro lado te recomiendo que valides los campos que no quieres que sean nulos en tu base de datos con la propiedad NOT NULL , asi te avitarás datos mal ingresados por fallas en el código.

También puedes validar los datos antes del insert.

```
<?php
    require_once "conexion.php"; 
    $conexion = conexion(); 
    $n = $_POST['nombre']; 
    $c = $_POST['correo']; 
    $f = $_POST['fechareg']; 
    $t = $_POST['telefono'];
    if( $n != '' &&  $c != '' && $f != '' && $t != '' ){
        $sql = "insert into llenado_formulario(nombre, correo, fechareg, celular) values('$n', '$c', '$f', '$t')";
        echo $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql); 
    }else{
        echo "error";
    }
?>
```

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Ya lo intente a tu manera amigo y aun no hay un resultado correcto, ahora se agregan puros campos vacios aunque tenga la comprobación.

Comment: en el PHP que hace el Insert, si haces un print_r($_POST) podrías ver cuales son los valores que estan llegando .. Lo has probado ?